# where is my php that I have installed

Tags: php, macos

I have installed php on my macbook , the phpinfo:

```
'/private/var/tmp/apache_mod_php/apache_mod_php-87~72/php/configure' '--prefix=/usr' '--mandir=/usr/share/man' '--infodir=/usr/share/info' '--disable-dependency-tracking' '--sysconfdir=/private/etc' '--with-apxs2=/usr/sbin/apxs' '--enable-cli' '--with-config-file-path=/etc' '--with-config-file-scan-dir=/Library/Server/Web/Config/php' '--with-libxml-dir=/usr' '--with-openssl=/usr' '--with-kerberos=/usr' '--with-zlib=/usr' '--enable-bcmath' '--with-bz2=/usr' '--enable-calendar' '--disable-cgi' '--with-curl=/usr' '--enable-dba' '--enable-ndbm=/usr' '--enable-exif' '--enable-fpm' '--enable-ftp' '--with-gd' '--with-freetype-dir=/BinaryCache/apache_mod_php/apache_mod_php-87~72/Root/usr/local' '--with-jpeg-dir=/BinaryCache/apache_mod_php/apache_mod_php-87~72/Root/usr/local' '--with-png-dir=/BinaryCache/apache_mod_php/apache_mod_php-87~72/Root/usr/local' '--enable-gd-native-ttf' '--with-icu-dir=/usr' '--with-ldap=/usr' '--with-ldap-sasl=/usr' '--with-libedit=/usr' '--enable-mbstring' '--enable-mbregex' '--with-mysql=mysqlnd' '--with-mysqli=mysqlnd' '--without-pear' '--with-pdo-mysql=mysqlnd' '--with-mysql-sock=/var/mysql/mysql.sock' '--with-readline=/usr' '--enable-shmop' '--with-snmp=/usr' '--enable-soap' '--enable-sockets' '--enable-sqlite-utf8' '--enable-suhosin' '--enable-sysvmsg' '--enable-sysvsem' '--enable-sysvshm' '--with-tidy' '--enable-wddx' '--with-xmlrpc' '--with-iconv-dir=/usr' '--with-xsl=/usr' '--enable-zend-multibyte' '--enable-zip' '--with-pcre-regex=/usr'
```

While I can use it, But I don't know where it is. I can't use the command `php -v`.
Result:

```
-bash: php: command not found
```

`whereis php` doesn't find anything either. How to make `php -v` run correctly ?

When I access to the `/usr/html/phpinfo.php` through the browser , output is ok. In other words , I think it's working correctly. (`/usr/html/` is my nginx root) 
The command `/usr/bin/php -v` doesn't work.
The result of `mdfind -name php`(I have removed the php-file of my app)

```
/usr/share/zsh/5.0.2/functions/_php
/usr/share/vim/vim73/syntax/php.vim
/usr/share/vim/vim73/indent/php.vim
/usr/share/vim/vim73/ftplugin/php.vim
/usr/share/vim/vim73/compiler/php.vim
/usr/share/vim/vim73/autoload/phpcomplete.vim
/usr/share/php
/usr/sbin/php-fpm
/private/etc/php.ini.default
/private/etc/apache2/other/php5.conf
/usr/lib/php
/System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.16/darwin-thread-multi-2level/Apache/TestRunPHP.pm
/System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.16/darwin-thread-multi-2level/Apache/TestHarnessPHP.pm
/System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.16/darwin-thread-multi-2level/Apache/TestConfigPHP.pm
/System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level/Apache/TestRunPHP.pm
/System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level/Apache/TestHarnessPHP.pm
/System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level/Apache/TestConfigPHP.pm
```

Comment: @deceze `mdfind -name php` the result is too many to I can't pick up the correct answer.`/usr/share/php -v`,`/usr/bin/php -v`,`/usr/lib/php -v`, neither one is OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`--prefix=/usr` means that the binary will be located at `/usr/bin/php`

`--prefix` is a standard option to GNU configure and not special for PHP. If you are interested in how that standard options work, then you can read [this](http://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/html_node/Directory-Variables.html#Directory-Variables)

---

**Update**:

After you posted the output of `mdfind` it shows that you have only installed the php-fpm module: `/usr/sbin/php-fpm`. You need to additionally enable the php-cli module before compiling. Add the `--enable-cli` switch to your configure options

Comment: I also think so,but when I use the command `/usr/bin/php -v` the result : `-bash: /usr/bin/php: No such file or directory`

Comment: But when I access to the `/usr/html/phpinfo.php` through the browser , it's working correctly.

Comment: And what gives you `mdfind -name php` (as @deceze suggested?)

Comment: `/usr/html/` sounds weird

Comment: `mdfind -name php` the result is too many to I can't pick up the correct answer.

Comment: `/usr/html/` is my nginx root, I forgot to say.

Comment: can you post the output of `mdfind` ?

Comment: maybe install it once again is the best solution,I have posted the output

Comment: You have only installed the `php-fpm` module: `/usr/sbin/php-fpm`.. You need to additionally enable the `php-cli` module. Add the `--enable-cli` switch to your configure options

Comment: I told you: `--enable-cli` .. Btw, it seems that you don't have much experience with compilation. Why don't you install a binary package?